# How do I get the coordinates of a click on vector feature/layer in OpenLayers transformed to another projection system?

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to get the coordinates of the click when the user clicks on any place on the base map. I have checked the answer to similar problem here:
[How do I get the coordinates of a click on vector feature/layer in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16906/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-click-on-vector-feature-layer-in-openlayers)

But, I need the coordinates transformed to the projection system used by my map: that is 
EPSG:900913,  Spherical Mercator Projection and passed to a html textbox.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [OpenLayers.LonLat.transform()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html#OpenLayers.LonLat.transform) function.

If you want to transform between EPSG 4326 & EPSG:900913, Openlayers can do it for you.

If you want to transform between some other projections, then you will have to use the Proj4js library.

Include in your page:

```
<script src="http://proj4js.org/lib/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
```

Then in your javascript

```
var lonlat = yourpoint.clone();
lonlat.transform(map.projection, <target projection>);
```

Note that transform() changes the actual object, so if you need the orignal object for something, remember to clone it.